# Does Xubuntu require Vera-Crypt to be installed during installation?

Tags: veracrypt

On initial install of Xubuntu do I have to incorporate Veracrypt during install or is that something that can be done after installation?

What is the best method to do a full disk encryption on a fresh clean install.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in Full Disk Encryption via LUKS. It's part of the setup for installation during the partition options.

If you go another route you either won't have *full* disk encryption (such as with a home folder only encryption) or you will have to manually copy your entire disk to a new encrypted volume.